# Is it possible to limit a random link script ( Random_All ) to a certain area?

Tags: javascript, random, generator

I'm having trouble limiting the random_all script to just a certain area. I tried to do this by hiding the div containers on my page, but that didn't hide the links from the script itself.

Does anyone know how to modify the `document.links.length-1`  or the window.location to just perform the random link generator in just the  `<body>` or a specified section of my page?

Here's the page i'm working with: http://www.eointhomassharkey.com/random

Thanks for your help.

```
<script>

function random_all(){
var myrandom=Math.round(Math.random()*(document.links.length-1))
window.location=document.links[myrandom].href
} 
//-->
</script>

<center><h3>#<a href="javascript:random_all()">RANDOM</a></h3>
</center>
```

Comment: Removed the jquery tag from your question. Assume you're not using it?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [query selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). They allow you to select a particular set of elements using css selectors.

In your case something like this:

```
function random_all() {
  var myrandom=Math.round(Math.random()*(document.links.length-1));
  var filteredLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.some-container-class a');
  window.location=filteredLinks[myrandom].href;
}
```

Comment: Still haven't had any luck with this. Anyone know of ways I can exclude specific links from a random generator not web page sections?